# CakePHP2.3: Controller method with param throws "requested address not found" on redirect

Tags: php, controller, cakephp-2.3

**Goal:** collect some basic pre-registration info so as to fetch the right view, and manage a few other details.

**Problem:** I can't seem to pass anything to the intended method; if I pass nothing, the `else` condition evaluates and the redirect occurs. If, however, `$preReg` is passed, *no matter what it contains* I cannot shake this error:

> **Invalid user Error: The requested address**
>
> *'/myAppName/users/registerUser/userType%26amp%3B7%26amp%3B3%26amp%3B1%26amp%3B5%26amp%3B%26amp%3B%26amp%3B'*
>
> was not found on this server.

This is the initial method:

```
public function register() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->request->url == "users/register") {
                    $this->redirect("registerUser/".urlencode(implode("&amp;",$this->request->data('Registration'))));
                }
            }
                 // various other logic
}
```

Which should pass some completely insensitive but useful information to another method of the same controller:

```
public function registerUser($preReg = null) {
        if ($preReg) {
            $data = explode("&amp;",urldecode($preReg));
            $this->view($preReg['UserType']);
            $groups = $this->User->Group->find('all', array('conditions' => array("name =".strtolower(substr($preReg['UserType'], -4)))));
            $this->set(compact($groups, $data));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("A few details are required before registration can begin. Please fill out the form below.");
            $this->redirect("register");
        }
    }
```

The view this goes to, for the moment, is just this simple:

```
<h1>THIS IS HOW I KNOW I GOT HERE</h1>
<?php pr($this->request);?>
```

I'd love to understand *why* this happens and what I'm doing wrong, especially in terms of my thinking. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just a nub; this is the standard error message when Cake cannot resolve a URL. In the case above, the `registerUser()` method wasn't completing properly; `$this->view()` isn't the proper way to set a view (should have been using a call to `$this->render($preReg['UserType']`. My broken controller logic created a circumstance where Cake's internal logic wasn't able to resolve my URL consequent to my accidental attempt at interfering with it.